# How to solve these html2canvas scroll Bug on Edge and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, html2canvas

I'm working with html2canvas and I want to print specific div area.
My idea is take a screenshot and open the image with new window,then print it.
But I had following problems on Edge and Chrome.
This is the div area I want to print:

[image]

and here is my code:

```
    <Button id="printCalendarButton" onclick="printCalendar()">Print</Button>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">       
      function printCalendar(){
       html2canvas(document.querySelector("#calendarContainer")).then(canvas => {
            window.open().document.write('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
          });
       }
    </script>
```

On Chrome and Edge:

[image]

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. We currently have no idea where & how you are calling that `printCalendar` function, so we can’t tell whether anything “jumping” has to do with that or not.

Comment: it's the name of function

Comment: And? A function _name_ does not tell us anything about where and how it is getting called.